# Python: How do I retrieve a value from a dict?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm given two dates `from_date` and `to_date`. From them i've extracted the difference between the dates in years, months and days.
e.g. `results = {'year':1,'month':6,'day':19}`

I need to extract the next 'greater key' in this dict based from the results dates:

```
 dates={
     "1-day":"1D",
     "5-day":"5D",
     "1-month":"1M",
     "3-month":"3M",
     "6-month":"6M",
     "1-year":"1A",
     "2-year":"2A",
     "5-year":"5A",
     "10-year":"10A"
 }
```

Here are same sample outputs:
`results = {'year':7,'month':6,'day':19}` returns `10A`
`results = {'year':0,'month':6,'day':0}` returns `6M`
`results = {'year':0,'month':6,'day':19}` returns `1A`
`results = {'year':0,'month':0,'day':3}` returns `5D`
`results = {'year':12,'month':6,'day':19}` returns `10A #anything after 10 years returns 10A`
`results = {'year':3,'month':0,'day':0}` returns `5A`
`results = {'year':5,'month':0,'day':0}` returns `5A`
`results = {'year':5,'month':0,'day':1}` returns `10A`
`results = {'year':2,'month':6,'day':19}` returns `5A`
`results = {'year':3,'month':6,'day':19}` returns `5A`

I can't figure out how to do this. Can anyone guide me some insight as to how to solve this?
If I didn't explain things properly, please let me know.

Comment: *"... returns 3A"* ... which doesn't exist in your dict.

Comment: @OlvinRoght i noticed that, i fixed it

Comment: it's not hard to write a solution, but you should replace keys of `dates` with numbers (or with tuples).

Comment: Does it have to be *this*…? This is fairly easy when working with dates and their differences as `timedelta` and an `if..elif` chain…

Comment: @deceze what would the if  elif chain be comparing?

Comment: Forget about the `dates` dictionary (except as your own reference) and don't let that one confuse you finding a solution. Just look at the `results` dict and try to figure out how YOU would reason to find the required output. Then write your solution.

Comment: @altoids with another timedelta

Comment: Please explain this `results = {'year':12,'month':6,'day':19} returns 10A`

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh anything after 10 years returns 10A

Answer (score 0):

Your dates are essentially epochs of different sizes.  You can create your own class that handles comparing the time differences to each epoch and store it as a property.

Below is an example class that does just that.

```py
class TimeDiff:
    def __init__(self, year=0, month=0, day=0, calc_next=True):
        self.year = year
        self.month = month
        self.day = day
        self._epochs = {
            '1D': {'day': 1},
            '5D': {'day': 5},
            '1M': {'month': 1},
            '3M': {'month': 3},
            '6M': {'month': 6},
            '1A': {'year': 1},
            '2A': {'year': 2},
            '5A': {'year': 5},
            '10A': {'year': 10},
        }
        if calc_next:
            self._next_epoch = self.find_next_epoch()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<TimeDiff {self.year} year, {self.month} month, {self.day} day>'

    def find_next_epoch(self):
        for ename, edict in self._epochs.items():
            ep = self.__class__(**edict, calc_next=False)
            if ep >= self:
                self._next_epoch = ename
                return ename
    
    @property
    def next_epoch(self):
        return self._next_epoch
    
    def __ge__(self, other):
        cond = (
            ((self.year > other.year))
            | (
                (self.year == other.year) 
                & (self.month > other.month)
              )
            | (
                (self.year == other.year) 
                & (self.month == other.month)
                & (self.day >= other.day)
              )
        )
        return cond
```

Here are the tests:

```py
results = {'year':7,'month':6,'day':19}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'10A'

results = {'year':0,'month':6,'day':0}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'6M'

results = {'year':0,'month':6,'day':19}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'1A'

results = {'year':0,'month':0,'day':3}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'5D'

results = {'year':12,'month':6,'day':19}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'10A'

results = {'year':3,'month':0,'day':0}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'5A'

results = {'year':5,'month':0,'day':0}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'10A'

results = {'year':5,'month':0,'day':1}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'10A'

results = {'year':2,'month':6,'day':19}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'5A'

results = {'year':3,'month':6,'day':19}
TimeDiff(**results).next_epoch
# returns:
'5A'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
dates={
     "1-day":"1D",
     "5-day":"5D",
     "1-month":"1M",
     "3-month":"3M",
     "6-month":"6M",
     "1-year":"1A",
     "2-year":"2A",
     "5-year":"5A",
     "10-year":"10A"
 }

def get_dtcat(res, dates=dates):
    lvs=list(res.keys())
    for k, v in dates.items():
        klvl=lvs.index(k.split("-")[-1])
        if((klvl>0 and res[lvs[max(klvl-1,0)]] + res[lvs[max(klvl-2,0)]]==0) or (klvl==0)):
            if(int(k.split("-")[0])>res[lvs[klvl]]) or (int(k.split("-")[0])==res[lvs[klvl]] and (sum(res.values())==res[lvs[klvl]])):
                return v
    return v
```

For your test cases this will output:

```py
print(get_dtcat({'year': 7, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
10A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 0}))
6M
print(get_dtcat({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
1A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 0, 'month': 0, 'day': 3}))
5D
print(get_dtcat({'year': 12, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
10A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 3, 'month': 0, 'day': 0}))
5A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 5, 'month': 0, 'day': 0}))
5A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 5, 'month': 0, 'day': 1}))
10A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 2, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
5A
print(get_dtcat({'year': 3, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
5A
```

Answer (score 0):

How about converting all the values contained in your `date` dict to a number of days?

Then for each `result` dict you would convert to days, calculate the diff between the result and all the values in the `dates` values and take the one with the smallest positive difference? Then you can add a case so that if there is no positive difference then you have a default output (10A in your example)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a slight variation of binary search:

```py
dates = {
    "1-day": "1D",
    "5-day": "5D",
    "1-month": "1M",
    "3-month": "3M",
    "6-month": "6M",
    "1-year": "1A",
    "2-year": "2A",
    "5-year": "5A",
    "10-year": "10A"
}

to_days = {
    'day': 1,
    'month': 31,
    'year': 12 * 31
}


def convert(parts):
    total = 0
    for k, v in parts.items():
        total += to_days[k] * v
    return total


def get_key(dt):
    parts = dt.split('-')
    return convert({parts[1]: int(parts[0])})


date_vals = [(get_key(k), v) for k, v in dates.items()]
date_vals.sort()

def get_next(target):
    target = convert(target)
    start = 0
    end = len(date_vals) - 1
    while start <= end:
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        mid_date, mid_val = date_vals[mid]
        if mid_date == target:
            return mid_val
        elif mid_date > target:
            if mid == 0 or date_vals[mid - 1][0] < target:
                return mid_val
            else:
                end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return date_vals[-1][1]


assert (get_next({'year': 7, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '10A')
assert (get_next({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 0}) == '6M')
assert (get_next({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '1A')
assert (get_next({'year': 0, 'month': 0, 'day': 3}) == '5D')
assert (get_next({'year': 12, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '10A')
assert (get_next({'year': 3, 'month': 0, 'day': 0}) == '5A')
assert (get_next({'year': 3, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '5A')
assert (get_next({'year': 5, 'month': 0, 'day': 1}) == '10A')
assert (get_next({'year': 2, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '5A')
assert (get_next({'year': 3, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}) == '5A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def func(dct):
    dates={
     "1-day":"1D",
     "5-day":"5D",
     "1-month":"1M",
     "3-month":"3M",
     "6-month":"6M",
     "1-year":"1A",
     "2-year":"2A",
     "5-year":"5A",
     "10-year":"10A"
    }
    dates1=[int(i.split('-')[0]) if 'day' in i else(int(i.split('-')[0])*30 if 'month' in i else(int(i.split('-')[0])*365 if 'year' in i else '')) for i in list(dates.keys())]
    dat=sum([v*365 if k=='year' else(v*30 if k=='month' else v) for k,v in dct.items()])

    idx=0
    for i, val in enumerate(dates1):
        if (val==dat)|(dat>val and i==len(dates1)-1):
            idx=i
        if dat>val and i!=len(dates1)-1:
            idx=i+1
        
            
    return dates[list(dates.keys())[idx]]
```

Output with you results cases:

```
print(func({'year': 7, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
10A
print(func({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 0}))
6M
print(func({'year': 0, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
1A
print(func({'year': 0, 'month': 0, 'day': 3}))
5D
print(func({'year': 12, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
10A
print(func({'year': 3, 'month': 0, 'day': 0}))
5A
print(func({'year': 5, 'month': 0, 'day': 0}))
5A
print(func({'year': 5, 'month': 0, 'day': 1}))
10A
print(func({'year': 2, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
5A
print(func({'year': 3, 'month': 6, 'day': 19}))
5A
```